# Prove that $x^3 + x^2 = 1$ has no rational solutions?

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, proof-verification, rational-numbers

Is this enough for a proof?:

$$x^3+x^2 = 1$$

I would factor and get: $x^2(x+1) = 1$

I would show that $x = \sqrt1$, which is rational but then what else would I have to show? $x+1=1$ which gives me $x=0$ and since $x$ cannot equal to $0$ as this would make the statement false ($0$ times anything is $0$). Is it enough to simply state this falsity or is there another way to express it?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: You cannot say that $x^2=1$ or $x+1=1$ from that factorisation. That only works if the right hand side is *zero*.

Comment: Assume $p/q$ is a solution, with $p$ and $q$ relatively prime. Then $(p/q)^3+(p/q)^2-1=0$, i.e. $p^3+qp^2+q^3=0$. The first two terms are multiples of $p$ so the last, $q^3$, must be divisible by $p$. But since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime then $p=\pm1$. Looking now at the last two terms we get that $q=\pm1$ too. We can check that $1^3+1^2-1\neq0$ and that $(-1)^3+(-1)^2-1\neq0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{1}$ is not irrational.

Comment: Your solution would make sense if $x\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @OR. That's basically the reasoning behind the rational roots theorem?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), a rational root would have to be $x=1$ or $x=-1$, but neither works.

Comment: What's with all the upvotes, friends? I barely did anything. This better not end up in my top answers. ;)

Comment: The upvotes are for the simplicity.  You can't get any better than a 1 sentence answer.

Comment: @tylerc0816 Fair enough. I'm not really complaining. ;)

Comment: It’s really the only answer to be given, and you won the lottery by being first. Bask in it.

Comment: I'm +1ing it just so it will be in your top answers. =p J/K - it really is a strait forward, easy to understand, and complete answer (with a link to external sources and everything!)

Comment: @EtherDragon The damage is already done, it is my top answer!  ;)

Answer (score 29):

Let's assume $x = p/q$. $p$ and $q$ integers without a common factor. Then,
$$
p^{3} + p^{2}q = q^{3}
$$

It's is only satisfied whenever $p$ and $q$ are simultaneously even. It contradicts the initial hypothesis that we can set $x = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ has not common factors.
$$
\mbox{Then,}\quad x \not\in {\mathbb Q}
$$

Answer (score 1):

### Theorem

The solution satisfying the following equation
$$
A \times B =0
$$
is $A=0$ (for any $B$) or $B=0$ (for any $A$).

You cannot apply the same pattern for the case in which the right hand side is not zero. Why?
For example,
$$
A\times B = 2
$$
If you choose $A=2$ then $B$ must be $1$ (rather than for any $B$). If you choose $B=2$ then $A$ must be $1$ (rather than for any $A$).

### Back to your question

If you want to find the solution of
$$x^2(x+1) =1$$
you have to make sure the right hand side equals to 0.

\begin{align*}
x^2(x+1) &=1\\
x^3 + x^2 -1 &=0
\end{align*}

To prove the equation has no rational solution see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529227/prove-that-x3-x2-1-has-no-rational-solutions#comment1131073_529227) comment.

Comment: How is this an answer?