# How can I prove this equation has no solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Solve the equation
$$-x^3 + x + 2 =\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5.}$$
I tried. The equation equavalent to
$$\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} - 2 + x^3 - x=0.$$
$$\dfrac{3x^2+4x+1}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}+x^3 - x=0.$$
$$\dfrac{(x+1)(3x+1)}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}+ (x+1) x (x-1)=0.$$
$$(x+1)\left [\dfrac{3x+1}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}+  x (x-1)=0\right ]=0.$$
How can I prove the equation
$$\dfrac{3x+1}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}+  x (x-1)=0$$
has no solution?

Comment: @Deepak Please see the last equation in my tried.

Comment: Oh i see what you're doing. Never mind.

Comment: While not formal, I always tend to get my graphing tool and graph both sides as functions. In this case it would be clear...

Comment: @imranfat Using graph is not a solution.

Comment: @minthao_2011 True, like I said, it is a rather informal approach, however, IF the curves intersect, what does that mean? It's a start...

Comment: @Deepak Hey, that cat of yours looks very intelligent, borderline looking down on me :)

Comment: @imranfat Haha, not my cat, that's "serious cat" :)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by squaring both sides of the equation:

$$ (-x^2 + x +2)^2 = 3x^2 +4x +5$$

$$x^6 -2x^4-4x^3-2x^2-1 =0$$

As suggested by Deepak, $x = -1$ is a solution.
You can factorise fully by dividing the above polynomial by $x+1$ to obtain other factors and solutions (if any).

Comment: OK. It is not simple 
$(x+1) \left(x^5-x^4-x^3-3
   x^2+x-1\right)=0$

Comment: How can I prove the equation $x^5-x^4-x^3-3
   x^2+x-1=0$ has no solution?

Comment: Yes, it appears that polynomial has no real roots.

Comment: I think It is not simple. Can you prove it?

Comment: You may want to see this post for more-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529227/prove-that-x3-x2-1-has-no-rational-solutions/529228.

Comment: Note that, every an odd polynomial always has solution. Therefore, I think, we must use the condition $-x^3 + x + 2 \geqslant  0$. But, now I can not.

Comment: your link is problem equation has no rational solution.

Comment: Squaring introduces extra roots : $x^5-x^4-x^3-3 x^2+x-1=0$ has a real root close to $x=2.1$. This is normal since a polynomial of odd degree always shows a solution.

Comment: \begin{align*}
x^5-x^4-x^3-3x^2+x-1&=x^5-x^3-2x^2-(x^2-x+1)-x^4\\
& =x^2 (x^3-x-2)-(x^2-x+1)-x^4
\end{align*}
From the given equation, we have
$x^3-x-2 \leqslant 0.$ Another way $x^2-x+1 >0$ and $x^4 \geqslant 0.$
Therefore
$$x^5-x^4-x^3-3x^2+x-1<  0.$$

Answer (score 1):

hint: 
edit 2: 
when $x>1$, there is no solution, when $-\dfrac{1}{3} \le x \le 0$, there is no solution also.

when $0\le x\le 1, x(1-x) < f(x)=\dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{5}}$

and 
$\dfrac{3x+1}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}\ge \dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{5}}$

so only possible is $x <-\dfrac{1}{3}$

now there is a $g(x)=\dfrac{4}{3}(3x+1)$

you need to prove $\dfrac{3x+1}{\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5} + 2}> g(x) >x(1-x)$ which is easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have a good idea. I change by $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(3x+1)$. And a new prolem is if $x\in (0,1)$, we have not yet prove the equation has no solution. Please try again.

Comment: @minthao_2011 ya, sorry for the mistake. I add new part.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer since based on approximations.*

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{-x^3 + x + 2 -\sqrt{3x^2 + 4x + 5}}{x+1}$$ Around $x=0$ it looks as a parabola; so the function can be approximated by a Taylor series to third order. So, around $x=0$, we have $$f(x)\approx \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}-1\right) x+\left(1-\frac{41}{10
   \sqrt{5}}\right) x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ So, if the approximating function is $$g(x)= \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}-1\right) x+\left(1-\frac{41}{10
   \sqrt{5}}\right) x^2$$The quadratic does not show any real root and then $g(x)$ shows a maximum for $x_*=-\frac{5 \left(11 \sqrt{5}-73\right)}{1181}\approx 0.204925$ leading to $$g(x_*)=-\frac{9 \left(116 \sqrt{5}-233\right)}{1181}\approx -0.201063$$ which corresponds to the maximum. Using the full definition of $f(x)$, we should find $$f(x_*)\approx -0.200890$$

Numerically, the maximum value of $f(x)$ is found as $\approx -0.200889$ corresponding to $x=0.206212$.

Since the maximum value of $f(x)<0$, no other roots beside $x=-1$.